# Website navigation disappearing and reappearing after jQuery click (in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, flicker, nav

When newsletter in the bottom left corner of the screen is clicked this function is run:

```
$('#newsletterbtn').click(function() {
    $('#newsletterbtn').hide();
    $('.sub').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#email').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#email').animate({width:'97'},'slow');
});
```

Can be seen on [www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/](http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/)

It works fine in Safari and Firefox but in Chrome the navigation disappears momentarily and reappears a second later and I can't seem to see why. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Can you post an example or jsFiddle? At least post the HTML that is affected by the jQuery.

Comment: My Mistake it's at www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/ but I just had to return false at the end of the function!

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please either post it as answer and mark it as the accepted solution so others can find it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I made sure my function returned `false` :

```
$('#newsletterbtn').click(function() {
    $('#newsletterbtn').hide();
    $('.sub').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#email').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#email').animate({width:'97'},'slow');

    return false
});
```

Comment: Another solution is to call `event.preventDefault()` by passing an `event` argument into your `click()` function.